# Background color is not changing in DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, datatrigger

I have some problem while changing background color of Button using **datatrigger** but it is not happen.

My code is this

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.DataTrigger2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DataTrigger2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Button Height="50" Name="btn">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="YellowGreen"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Brown"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Purple"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Light"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="150"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="50"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <Button.Content>
        The Gaming World Inc.
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't see the `Button.Background` colour change when you click the mouse is because of the default `ControlTemplate` that defines what the it should look like in different states, eg. pressed, disabled. etc. These are defined in the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` section of the `ControlTemplate` and they potentially override your `Background` changes.

As simple proof of this, we can provide a basic `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` without the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` section and then you will see your `Background` colour change. Try this:

```
<Button Height="50" Name="btn">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="YellowGreen"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Brown"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Purple"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Light"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="150"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="50"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.Content>
            The Gaming World Inc.
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

You can find the original/default `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` control in the [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN... you may want to copy more of that `ControlTemplate` into your one to make your `Button` look more like the original one.

Comment: Can i use this method in control template for change background ?

Comment: If you're asking if you can use a `DataTrigger` in the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` section, then yes, you can. Otherwise, I didn't understand your question.